# How to access enum values in other classes in Swift?

Tags: swift, enums, scenekit

I am trying to set a property for a particle emitter in swift, using scenekit.
I feel really stupid as I cannot figure out how to set constants that are set up as enums.
Here's the code:

```
//Create emitter
let emitter = SCNParticleSystem()

//set up the emitter trying to use the enum values
emitter.birthLocation = SCNParticleBirthLocation.SCNParticleBirthLocationSurface

//I have tried a few other ways including:
emitter.birthLocation = .SCNParticleBirthLocationSurface
emitter.birthLocation = SCNParticleSystem.SCNParticleBirthLocation.SCNParticleBirthLocationSurface
```

This isn't the only thing I have had trouble with using enums in different classes so I figure I have something fundamentally wrong. 
The link to the apple framework reference in case anyone needs: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNParticleSystem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SCNParticleSystem

And finally my whole code just in case it's something else entirely that I'm doing wrong

```
import Foundation
import SceneKit

class NextLevelScene: SCNScene{

override init(){
    super.init()
    let nextLevel: SCNNode = SCNNode()
    let text: SCNGeometry = SCNText(string: "Next Level", extrusionDepth: 0.0)
    let material = UIColor.blueColor()
    text.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = material
    nextLevel.geometry = text

    let exp = SCNParticleSystem()
    exp.loops = true
    exp.birthRate = 5000
    exp.emissionDuration = 0.2
    exp.spreadingAngle = 180
    exp.particleDiesOnCollision = true
    exp.particleLifeSpan = 0.2
    exp.particleLifeSpanVariation = 0.05
    exp.particleVelocity = 20
    exp.particleVelocityVariation = 3
    exp.particleSize = 0.05
    exp.stretchFactor = 0.02
    exp.particleColor = UIColor.redColor()
    exp.emitterShape = text
    //Error here
    exp.birthLocation = SCNParticleBirthLocation.SCNParticleBirthLocationSurface
    self.addParticleSystem(exp, withTransform: SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(0, 0, 0, 0))


    self.rootNode.addChildNode(nextLevel)
}

required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you Command-click on `birthLocation` in the Xcode source file to get the
definition of the property, and then Command-click on `SCNParticleBirthLocation`
then you'll see that it is declared in Swift as

```
enum SCNParticleBirthLocation : Int {

    case Surface //particles are emitted on the surface of the emitter shape.
    case Volume //particles are emitted inside the volume of the emitter shape.
    case Vertex //particles are emitted on the vertices of the emitter shape.
}
```

so you simply need

```
emitter.birthLocation = SCNParticleBirthLocation.Surface
```

which can be shortened (due to automatic type inference) to

```
emitter.birthLocation = .Surface
```

Comment: Just want to add for anyone reading that the swift name for the constants only showed up in the docs for scenekit when I select "swift" in the top right hand corner of the webpage. Selecting "both" only shows the objective-C for some reason. This occurs on the page linked in OP as well as some others, but not all.